# DASH mpd add http header to all request

Tags: mpeg-dash

I'm writing a mdp file and I was looking for a way to specify (or modify) the HTTP header of all the request that the client do for a specific rapresentation. I would like to add an Authorization field inside of the http request. I was hoping to do so without edit the client's sw.

I have read the ISO/IEC 23009-1 but I have not found anything about it. Does someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean add the same base Url to all requests then this is possible and you can simply specify a base URL in the DASH manifest itself. It looks as simple as:

```html
<BaseURL>http://example.com/ondemand/</BaseURL>
```

There is a complete example at the time of writing on the Mozilla pages including the line above here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Setting_up_adaptive_streaming_media_sources

There is also a new DASH standard, still in definition phase so most likely hard to find implemtation at this point, designed to support a token based accesss authentication mechanism:

> DASH-IF IMPLEMENTATION GUIDELINES: TOKEN-BASED ACCESS CONTROL FOR DASH (TAC)
>   Scope
>
> The scope of this document is to define a token-based access control mechanism and to enable the signaling of Authentication and Authorization (AA) protocols for DASH-based streaming. An Access Token is a proof that a DASH client or user of the client have been successfully authenticated and authorized in some pre-determined AA Systems to access a particular DASH resource, e.g. DASH segments or MPDs. This document defines an Access Token format for accessing DASH resources and its transport between a DASH client and a server, hence ensuring interoperability between content providers and content delivery networks. The document focuses on the signaling and exchange mechanisms to facilitate Access Token-protected requests for the delivery of MPDs, licenses, keys and segments. This document can be used in addition to the general DASH-IF Interoperability Points.

The document is available here: https://dashif.org/guidelines/

Comment: Hi Mick,
I know that you could use the <BaseURL> tag but unfortunately I need also to specify the header of the http request done by the client. I was wondering if there is a way to so.

Thank you

Comment: Ah, ok - see updated answer above. This may help you but it is very new so will likely take some time to roll out.